# Give required validation to a group of checkbox formed in ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I wanna give required validation to a group of checkboxes formed using ng-repeat. So far I have tried

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="styp in ship_type_list">
     <div>
         <input type="radio" id="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}" ng-model="formData.ship_type" ng-value="styp.id" name="ship_type" required>
         <label for="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}"> {{styp.name}} </label>
     </div>
     <div ng-show="orderForm.$submitted || orderForm.ship_type.$touched">
         <span ng-show="orderForm.ship_type.$error.required" class="text-danger">Select ship type.</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Still unable to validate. Thanx in adv.

Answer (score 0):

User ng-required for validation

```
 <input type="radio" id="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}" ng-model="formData.ship_type" ng-value="styp.id" name="ship_type"  ng-required="value.length==0">
```

Answer (score 0):

What problem you face I don't understand. But, I solved the issues I faced in your code. This is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MSnpi2LzX0GMbcqiFZ3x?p=preview)

```
<form name="orderForm" ng-submit="call()">
    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="styp in ship_type_list">
         <div>
             <input type="radio" id="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}" ng-model="formData.ship_type" ng-value="styp.id" name="ship_type" required>
             <label for="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}"> {{styp.name}} </label>
         </div>
    </div>  
    <div ng-show="orderForm.$submitted || orderForm.ship_type.$touched">
             <span ng-show="orderForm.ship_type.$error.required" class="text-danger">Select ship type.</span>
         </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Check the array length in the ng-required attribute of the checkboxes.

```
<input type="radio" id="input_ship_type{{styp.id}}" ng-model="formData.ship_type" ng-value="styp.id" name="ship_type"  ng-required="value.length==0">
```